# Inline Signature Images in Outlook - without the attachment flag

Tags: microsoft-outlook

as this is my first question in this context, I hope it is rightfully placed here. Years ago I created a newsletter on a php-driven website and was able to embed images in a way, that they not even appeared as attachments on the receiving end. Like Apple seems to embed the pics in their email bodies.
In my workflows it is quite helpful to see on the first glance if there are attachments on an email. But I collide with this since my own signature appears as an attachment.

All web is giving me about this is to change the format from plain text to html, but that's the solution to a different problem, as I understand it.
The question is: Can images be embedded in outlook emails, so that no attachment-notification is shown? I want to have that only for actual attachments (I hope you know what I mean).

Any help is much appreciated.
Erik

**Update**: Problem remains, just on a higher level. I read that signature images should not be scaled in any way. Since all this stuff with images is new, MS Outlook scales the attachment images based on their size in cm. I do not want to wait until more people use Outlook on screens for a change and MS corrects this to pixel. "Reset" just does nothing. So for the time being my 214X40px PNG (quite small and pretty) is "converted" to 2,82X15,1 cm (not small at all and seriously ugly.). This may fit to Outlooks overall UI style, but not to any anthroposophic sense of aesthetics.
Any ideas?

Comment: Almost forgot: externally linking of the images is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Answer/solution below - it's about the genuine resolution with specific dpi settings. But see yourself. Once more MS Outlook's throne for best usability ever is in danger... ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking for a MS-Outlook-ONLY solution here you will definitely need to switch to HTML format for your emails and then provide [data-uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) for your images.
Like so:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Comment: Well, I like this one even better than the solution intended by MS. I'll try it out some time! :D

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake was on my side, although microsoft was not really helping here.
For instance there is no hint to the resolution of *.pngs in windows explorer's file properties. There is no hint to the resolution in outlook signature panel.
It is not explained, why there are centimeters instead of pic cells.
Solution as follows...

- Outlook has the deep albeit secret wish for images with resolution of 96 dpi
  -( Adobe Illustrator exported my elements in 36dpi, for whatever reason)
- I opened the siganture editor from the signature menu in some new e-mail
- delete the old picture, inserted new one from source with 96dpi

done.
Completely without thanks to Microsoft.

Thanks Michael from
https://superuser.com/questions/211020/prevent-outlook-2010-insert-picture-resizing-image
for further inspiration. Maybe all that would have fitted there better than here.

Answer (score 0):

Is your mail server exchange server?

I have read a blog on [How to make images display correctly in email signatures (not as attachments)](https://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/make-images-display-correctly-email-signatures-not-attachments/) for your reference.

Hope this help.